# Нужна помощь с Local Storage

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой вот скрипт, для выбора количество записей в таблице на странице

```
$(document).ready(() =>
{
    $("#rowPerPage").on("change", () =>
    {
        var pages = $("#rowPerPage>option:selected").text();
        //var pages = 15;
        var form = $("form.search.pull-left");

        var input = $("input.rawOnpage").attr(
                {"value": pages}
        );
        $(input).appendTo(form);

        //localStorage.setItem('value', pages);

        document.getElementById("filtAccept").click();
    });
});
```

Проблема в том что при переходе на разные страницы это значение скидывается, можно ли как-то сохранить значение переменной `pages` в `localStorage`, чтобы при переходе на другие страницы, значение в `select` оставалось одним?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$(document).ready(() =>
{
 var tempPages = localStorage.getItem('pages');
 if(tempPages != null){
    $("#rowPerPage").val(tempPages);
 }

 $("#rowPerPage").on("change", () =>
    {
        var pages = $("#rowPerPage>option:selected").text();
        //var pages = 15;
        var form = $("form.search.pull-left");

        var input = $("input.rawOnpage").attr(
                {"value": pages}
        );
        $(input).appendTo(form);

        localStorage.setItem('pages', pages);

        document.getElementById("filtAccept").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Получается что сохраняет, но на другой странице все равно отображается 25 записей, хотя в `select` показывает 15, у меня страница перегружается при выборе в `select`, а при таком способе оно отображает 15, но по факту 25, но все равно спасибо, ваш код работает правильно, просто к моему случаю это не применимо.